# HAML output href without parsing

Tags: haml

I'm trying to output an a tag in HAML like this:

```
%a{:href => '<?php url(); ?>'} Testing
```

It's a unique situation where a HAML generated .html file is being included as a PHP file, which is why it is being done this way.

The problem is HAML compiles this as:

`<a href="&lt;?php url(); ?&gt;">Testing</a>`

Any ideas on how to get it to not parse the `<>` inside

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`escape_attrs`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#escape_attrs-instance_method) option to `false`.

From the command line you can use `--no-escape-attrs`, otherwise add `:escape_attrs => false` to your Haml options.